# Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

When I try to pass a MovieClip through a function I get the error:

"Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip"

Room generation class:

```
public var generatedRoom:Array;

public function enemyPack():void
    {
        //trace(generatedRoom[createdRooms]);
        var random:int = Main.getRandom(0,5);

        switch(random)
        {
            case 0:
                Main.spawnEnemy(roomX+Main.getRandom(50, room.width-50),generatedRoom[createdRooms],roomY+Main.getRandom(50, room.height-50));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Enemy class:

```
public function spawn(setX:int,setY:int, inRoom:MovieClip ,b:int = 0):void
    {
        timeToSlow = Main.getRandom(500,1500)
        type = b;
        isDestroyed = false;
        switch(type)
        {
            case 0:
                life = 100 + (Math.pow(Main.dific,4));

                maxLife = life;
                model = new MC_EnemigoD();
                bulletSpeed = Main.getRandom(3,6);
                timeToMove = 400;
                bulletModel = new MC_BulletE();
                speed = 1 + (Main.nivel)/2;
                aggro = 250;
                break;
            case 1:
                life = 125 + (Math.pow(Main.dific,4));
                maxLife = life;
                model = new MC_EnemigoC();
                speed = 0.5 /*+ (Main.nivel)/2*/;
                break;
            case 2:
                life = 500 + (Math.pow(Main.dific,4));
                maxLife = life;
                model = new MC_BossM();
                speed = 1 + (Main.nivel)/2;
                timeToMove = Main.getRandom(400,600);
                bulletModel = new MC_BulletC();
                bulletSpeed = Main.getRandom(6,9);
                timeToShoot = Main.getRandom(1500,2000);
                aggro = 400;
                break;
            case 3:
                life = 400 + (Math.pow(Main.dific,4));
                maxLife = life;
                model = new MC_Troll();
                speed = 0.6 /* + (Main.nivel)/2*/;
                break;
            case 4:
                life = 1000 + (Math.pow(Main.dific,4));
                maxLife = life;
                model = new MC_BossB();
                model.scaleX = 0.5;
                model.scaleY = 0.5;
                speed = 3 + (Main.nivel)/2;
                break;
        }
        model.addChild(shadow);


        //Main.render.
        Main.render.addChild(model);
        model.gotoAndPlay("spawn")
        model.y = setY;
        model.x = setX;
        realHeight = model.height;
        realWidth = model.width;

        shadow.scaleX = model.scaleX + 0.1;
        shadow.scaleY = model.scaleY;
        shadow.x = (model.hitBox.width/2)+6-(shadow.width/2);
        shadow.y = (model.hitBox.height)-9;

        model.setChildIndex(shadow, 0);

        model.addChild(hpBar);
        hpBar.addChild(hpBarColor);
        hpBarColor.scaleY = 0.9;
        hpBarColor.scaleX = 0.97;
        hpBarColor.y = 1;
        hpBarColor.x = 1;
        hpBar.scaleY = 0.7;
        hpBar.x = (model.hitBox.width/2)+5-(hpBar.width/2);
        hpBar.y = (model.hitBox.height)+(hpBar.height);

        model.hitBox.visible = false;
    }
```

Main class:

```
public static function spawnEnemy(setX:int,setY:int, inRoom:MovieClip, t:int = 0):void
    {
        //trace(setX,setY)
        var temp:Enemy = new Enemy();
        temp.spawn(setX,setY, inRoom, t);
        allEnemies.push(temp);
    }
```

and when I trace the variable it returns [object MC_"myMovieClip"]

Comment: Hint: don't make everything a `static` function on `Main`. The mathematical utility function should be a top level function or in a separate class containing similar utility functionality. Spawning an enemy will eventually change the state of an object, it should not be static at all.

Comment: edited to add functions. The enemy spawning is pretty much throwaway code I want to make it work first.

Comment: Now add the line that the error occurs on and the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I guessed with the line causing your error*
looks like your `spawnEnemy` call

```
Main.spawnEnemy(roomX+Main.getRandom(50, room.width-50),//int
                generatedRoom[createdRooms],//a MovieClip?
                roomY+Main.getRandom(50, room.height-50)//int
                );//(int, MovieClip(?), int)
```

doesn`t have the right order of arguments:

```
spawnEnemy(setX:int,
           setY:int, 
           inRoom:MovieClip, 
           t:int = 0)//(int, int, MovieClip)
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks a lot, yes I was calling the arguments in the wrong order.